# dynamic array does not working properly

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I take  dynamic array as

```
double[] array = new double[10];
```

I put some values in it in run time, but if user put less then 
10 values like if user put 5 values in it instead of 10.
After that when i display the array first it's show the five value 
and after that start displaying 0 0 0 0 0. I just want to know is there any method
to get rid of using dynamic array in c#?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "dynamic" here. The array you declared has a fixed type and a fixed size. What are you trying to get rid of? And are you using Java or C#?

Comment: Are you trying to avoid using `double[]` or are you asking why your fixed array expects ten items?

Comment: Can you please remove either the C# tag or the Java tag?  This is a question about one language only - it's just not clear which one.

Comment: I am using c# .net framework. please suggest me how to take value dynamically in array and display them accordingly without using any extra space?

Comment: OK.  Please don't post questions with tags for languages that you're not interested in.  It's kind of rude to all the Java experts who might waste their time giving you an answer that's no use to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

double[10] is not a dynamic array. It's fixed length to 10 entries.

Try using List<double> instead. It's actually dynamic.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If you provide me with more code of what you're doing I can be more specific in my help.

Answer (score 0):

If I intend correctly, I think you may be looking for something like this:

```
var list = new List<double>();
list.Add(1.1);
list.Add(2.2);
list.Add(3.4);
list.Add(4.8);
list.Add(5.0);

var array = list.ToArray();

//here you can see that array has a length of 5
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"My array contains {array.Length}.");
```